# TJvXPButton как избавиться от белого пространства на углах?

Tags: delphi

Заменил обычные кнопки делфи на TJvXPButton из Jedi, но столкнулся  с тем, что на фоне, в месте закругления остаётся пространство [image: вот белое пространство в окне формы]

[image: Для сравнения сверху TJvXPButton, а снизу обычный button]

Answer (score 0):

Для одноцветных подложек можно установить цвет родителя:

```pascal
type
  THackWinControl = class(TWinControl);

procedure TMyForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  THackWinControl(myJvXPButton).Color := THackWinControl(myJvXPButton.Parent).Color;
end;
```

Comment: А в случае с не одноцветными подложками? Есть ли в данном случае варианты решения?

Comment: Сходу я не нашёл.